# Use return of a function in an if statement

Tags: javascript

**Edit 3 years later:**
I simply forgot to call the function.

---

So i have this code:

```
function xy () {
   return true
}
```

Can I now read the return in an if statement?
I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
if (xy == true){
  //stuff
}
```

Comment: After being declared `xy` will return the actual function. `xy()` will run it and give you the value returned.

Comment: while returning a boolean value or just a truthy or falsy value, you do not need to check against a boolean value. just `if (xy()) { /* stuff */ }` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call your method to retrieve the result.

```
if(xy() === true){
  //stuff
}
```

Comment: ok, i tried that and it works. But when I'm using it in my code (https://jsfiddle.net/jfw20w87/2/) it just returns an "undefined" can you help me there?

Comment: You need to read up on asynchronous calls and callbacks in javascript. There is a good thread on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call Also, if you need to use the result of a function in several comparisons you should store the result in a variable and compare with that or else your function will be called for each comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the function:

```
if (xy() == true){
```

Writing `xy` just references the function and the function object is not equal to `true`